# xarray.Dataset.where() method force-changes dtype of DataArrays to float

Tags: python, python-xarray

## Problem description

I have a dataset with `int`s in them, and I'd like to select a subdataset by some criteria but I would like to preserve the integer datatype. It seems to me that Xarray force-changes the integer data to float datatype.

## Example setup

#### Code

```
import numpy
import xarray

nums = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 13)
names = numpy.random.choice(["babadook", "samara", "jason"], 13)
data_vars = {"num": xarray.DataArray(nums), "name": xarray.DataArray(names)}
dataset = xarray.Dataset(data_vars)
print(dataset)
```

#### Output

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dim_0: 13)
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Data variables:
    num      (dim_0) int64 93 99 49 35 92 14 41 57 28 59 74 1 15
    name     (dim_0) <U8 'babadook' 'samara' 'samara' 'samara' 'jason' ...
In [16]:
```

## Example problem

#### Code

```
subdataset = dataset.where(dataset.num < 50, drop=True)
print(subdataset)
```

#### Output

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dim_0: 7)
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) int64 2 3 5 6 8 11 12
Data variables:
    num      (dim_0) float64 49.0 35.0 14.0 41.0 28.0 1.0 15.0
    name     (dim_0) <U32 'samara' 'samara' 'jason' 'babadook' 'jason' ...
```

Comment: According to the [its documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.where.html), `xarray.Dataset.where()` returns the "same type as caller" so this shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 6):

That's because with numpy (which xarray uses under-the-hood) ints don't have a way of representing `NaN`s. So with most `where` results, the type needs to be coerced to floats.

If `drop=True` and every value that is masked is dropped, that's not actually a constraint - you could have the new array retain its dtype, because there's no need for `NaN` values. That's not in xarray at the moment, but could be an additional feature.

Comment: Yes I guessed as much regarding NaN. Yes agreed regarding `drop=True`. Shall I open an issue on Github? I'll try to find time to submit a pull request if I may (and when I can).

Comment: Yes that's a good idea.

FWIW you can coerce back to ints yourself with `astype`. Not as good as if it were retained though

Comment: The problem with coercing back to ints myself is that I have to iterate through all the `DataArray`s that were converted to float. Cumbersome code aside, other complications arise when there are already `DataArray`s that are supposed to be `dtype` `float`.

Comment: If you want them all as `int` you don't need to iterate: `xr.Dataset({'a':xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10,3)), 'b': xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10))}).astype('int')` works.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the return type being changed to float64 is part of the documentation, indicating that this is wanted and not a bug.

For me this problem occured when I wanted to drop entries corresponding to a specific condition.

The issue can be avoided by using `drop_sel` instead
(https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.drop_sel.html)